# How to Find the Sum of ‘Add or Keep Sequence'

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sequence.

$a_{n}=a_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}+\dfrac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2}$ where $a_{0}=0$ and $n\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$.

So, it's
$a_{2k-1}=a_{k-1}+1$ or $a_{2k}=a_{k}$ for nonnegative integer $k$.

If I perform a continued divided by 2, and if the number $n$ lies in $2^{i}\leq n<2^{i+1}$,

$n=2(2(\dots(2(2+\_)+\_)+\dots)+\_)+\_$

There would be $i+1$ spaces, and by choosing where I put $0$ and $1$, the value changes accordingly.

So, there would be $P(i+1,j)$ choices if I want to put $1$ for $j$ times.

Then, it would be $a_{n}=j$.

I tried evaluating the sum of $a_{n}$ for an interval $2^{i}\leq n<2^{i+1}$, and I get $\displaystyle \sum^{i+1}_{j=0}\{j\cdot P(i+1,j)\}$.

I can't process it further because I'm stuck simplifying the expression. Please suggest a method.

Comment: *Hint:* Think of the base-2 (binary) representation of numbers.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000120

Comment: Thank you, Martin R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to evaluate $S_i=\sum_{n=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}a_n$. Every number in the summation for $S_{i+1}$ refers to a number $a_n$ in the summation for $S_i$, and the latter number $a_n$ (contributing to $S_i$) is so referenced precisely twice, namely by $a_{2n}=a_n$ and by $a_{2n+1}=a_n+1$. So while $a_n$ contributes its value to $S_i$, it contributes its value *twice* to $S_{i+1}$ (and all contributions to $S_i$ are so accounted for). But there are also contributions to $S_{i+1}$ of the $+1$ term in for the odd-index $a_{2n+1}$, and there as many of such contributions as there are $n$ with $2^i\leq n<2^{i+1}$, namely $2^i$. Therefore one gets the recurrence relation $S_{i+1}=2S_i+2^i$, with initial value $S_0=a_1=a_0+1=1$. From the initial values $1,4,12,32,80,192,\ldots$ it is not so hard to guess the general formula $S_i=(i+1)2^i$, and it is easy to check that this indeed satisfies the recurrence and the initial condition.